# GitHub - Can I receive email notifications using non-primary address

Tags: github

On GitHub I have multiple email addresses. I would like people to contact me using one address (i.e. show this address on my profile), but actually receive email notifications using another. However I don't see there being an option for that. Is there any way to do that? What's the point of letting the user keep multiple email addresses while only one ever gets to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is two different options: one in the **Profile** "Public email" and one in **Notification center** "Primary email address".